# Save button functionality getting fired before updatepanel code updated

Tags: asp.net

I have an `updatepanel` with multiple Dropdown. When user select value from the dropdown and hits <kbd>save</kbd> button (which is outside `updatepanel`) immediately, the dropdown previous selected value data is getting displayed instead of loading new value data.

So how to stop postback (save button) until `updatepanel` data gets loaded.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `UseSubmitBehavior="false"` should do the trick. But post your code.

Comment: Great! I've posted it as the answer to this question, if you could accept when it lets you that'd be great. :)

Answer (score 0):

`UseSubmitBehavior="false"` on the button will stop postback from happening.